# Display legends on a combined ggplot2 plot - Stacked bar and line

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a ggplot, which is a combination of a stacked graph and line graph

```
  ggplot() +
       geom_bar(data=smr2, aes(x=Pract, y=value, fill=variable), stat='identity') + 
       theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) +
       geom_line(data=summarised[,1:3], aes(x=Pract,y=YTDTarget, group=1),size = 1) +
       geom_point(data=summarised[,1:3], mapping = aes(x = Pract, y = YTDTarget),size=2.5)+
       geom_text_repel(data=summarised[,1:3], aes(x=Pract,y=YTDTarget,label=YTDTarget), size = 5)
```

I want to add the legend for line graph. But the part `group=1` seems to prevent this.

The graph I created is as [image]

Also, please help to change the name of the legend from variable to "Actuals"
This graph is for compare the Target(line graph) against actually achieved(stacked Bar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

To `geom_line` add dummy variable (to add it to legend - in this case I'm using `linetype`).

```
geom_line(data = summarised[,1:3], 
          aes(Pract, YTDTarget, group = 1, linetype = ""),
          size = 1)
```

To change legend name add `labs()` to your plot.

```
labs(fill = "Actuals",
     linetype = "My Line Name")
```